# Include hyper link in jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I include hyper link for "terms and conditions" in following jQuery function:

```
 create: function () {
            var pane = $(this).dialog("widget").find(".ui-dialog-buttonpane")
            $("<label class='terms-conditions'><input id='terms-conditions' type='checkbox' onchange='dialogDisable()'/> " +
                "<strong><?= _("I hereby accept the terms and conditions and have read the privacy statement.") ?></strong></label>").prependTo(pane);
            $('#terms-conditions').css('position', 'center');
        },
```

Comment: Update your HTML and jQuery as well in the question. Which helps much for providing the solution.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just add `<a href=...` around your text?   (Similar to deleted answer, but with `"` fixed)

Answer (score 1):

Solution was easy, I don't know why it wasn't working earlier.

```
<strong><?= _("I hereby accept the <a href='#' target='_blank'><u>terms and conditions</u></a> and have read the privacy statement.") ?></strong>
```